# How to fill non linear selection with some smoothness

Tags: gimp, fill

I want to create a outline around a selected area that I have cut away by 45 Degress. The issue is that the stroke has not a straight pattern and is also very pixelated.

I'd like to have a smooth outline to cover up these "hard" corners but am not sure how I can achieve this.

[image]

As you can see this is completely straight filled without any smoothing.
Btw. the "black" fill is a second layer behind the "redish" one with a growth selection by 1 px.
This then looks like this from the 100% zoom perspective:

[image]

Obviously not looking very professional.

Comment: Create a path a stroke it (Edit>Stroke path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't zoom in on raster images or you will see pixels. Raster images should be viewed at 100% (1:1).

Instead of using some black fill on a second layer underneath, perhaps use the Brush tool, set to a small size like 1 or 2 pixels, and medium hardness, then use  Edit > Stroke > Selection, and choose the "Stroke with a Paint Tool" option.